# Spring Boot classpath: vs relative path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In Spring Boot, to access a resource, say `myresource.json`, I can use both `classpath:` or a relative path, like `./myresource.json`

What is the difference? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `getResource()` on a specific application context, and the location path specified doesn't have a specific prefix like `./myresource.json`, you will get back a Resource type that is appropriate to that particular application context.

If `getResource()` was executed against a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext instance it will  return a `ClassPathResource`.If the same method was executed against a `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` instance, you'd get back a `FileSystemResource`. For a `WebApplicationContext`, you'd get back a `ServletContextResource`, and so on.
As such, you can load resources in a fashion appropriate to the particular application context.

On the other hand, you may also force `ClassPathResource` to be used, regardless of the application context type, by specifying the special `classpath`: prefix.

[See this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)